# Make a number a percentage

Tags: javascript, math

What's the best way to strip the "0."XXX% off a number and make it a percentage?  What happens if the number happens to be an int?

```
var number1 = 4.954848;
var number2 = 5.9797;

$(document).ready(function() {    
    final = number1/number2;
    alert(final.toFixed(2) + "%");
});
```

Answer (score 243, accepted):

A percentage is just:

```
(number_one / number_two) * 100
```

No need for anything fancy:

```js
var number1 = 4.954848;
var number2 = 5.9797;

alert(Math.floor((number1 / number2) * 100)); //w00t!
```

Comment: to keep the pct decimal: var pct = (num*100).toFixed(1) + "%";

Comment: alert(~~((number1 / number2) * 100));  as the Math.floor is slower than ~~ :)

Comment: Why `Math.floor`? And not `Math.round`? Even in your example `4.954848 / 5.9797` is closer to `83%` than to `82%` your code outputs.

Comment: @nyxz Ugg-- you write code for humans, not machines.  Unless you are in some super-tight critical loop, `~~` is much less readable than `Math.floor`

Comment: @gaazkam so make another answer that answers like that if you want. Please do not change code in answers like that...

Comment: @Neal Any explanation why you think `floor` is superior to `round`?

Comment: No reason that I know of. 83% of all percentages are made up anyway

Comment: Who needs a formal education when you have SO! :-) thanks so much (2.56 calories saved for not having to figure it out my self)

Comment: Use Math.round() ... it's not worth debate.  Math.round() rounds up, equal, or down...  while Math.floor() only rounds equal or down.

Answer (score 75):

```
((portion/total) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%'
```

Answer (score 53):

The best solution, where `en` is the English locale:

`fraction.toLocaleString("en", {style: "percent"})`

Comment: Beware for support or not on smartphones.... Currently the support is not that ideal.

Comment: (9.23).toLocaleString("en", {style: "percent"}) returns "923%", is there a way to solve it?

Comment: @slorenzo 9.23 is in fact 923%. Assuming you want 9.23%, you would need to divide 9.23 by 100 and then try the conversion.

Comment: @slorenzo To get the decimal digits as well you could try something like `fraction.toLocaleString("en", { style: "percent", minimumFractionDigits: 2 })` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29773435/411428

Answer (score 21):

Well, if you have a number like `0.123456` that is the result of a division to give a percentage, multiply it by 100 and then either round it or use `toFixed` like in your example.

```
Math.round(0.123456 * 100) //12
```

Here is a jQuery plugin to do that:

```
jQuery.extend({
    percentage: function(a, b) {
        return Math.round((a / b) * 100);
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
alert($.percentage(6, 10));
```

Comment: Where is `jQuery.round` and `jQuery.divide` and `jQuery.multiply`

Comment: @Xeon06 hmmm the OP seems to have switched his mind. weird. my answer **did not** have enough jQuery in it.

Comment: @Raynos I had started on a multiply using a loop and a round using string manipulation but I gave up on the division.

Answer (score 2):

```
var percent = Math.floor(100 * number1 / number2 - 100) + ' %';
```

Answer (score 2):

Most answers suggest appending '%' at the end. I would rather prefer `Intl.NumberFormat()` with `{ style: 'percent'}`

```js
var num = 25;

var option = {
  style: 'percent'

};
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", option);
var percentFormat = formatter.format(num / 100);
console.log(percentFormat);
```

Comment: doesn't work with percentages below zero.

Answer (score 0):

[Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) is a library I created that can can format numbers, currency, percentages and has support for localization.

`numeral(0.7523).format('0%') // returns string "75%"`

[numeral.js](/questions/tagged/numeral.js)

Comment: Last commit for `numeral.js` was 27 Mar 2017. Either the library is perfect (no defects) or it is no longer actively maintained. As of 28 Jan 2019 the project has 135 open issues with the oldest being from Nov 2012. The number of open issues with no commit in almost 2 years suggests that the project is no longer looked after. Happy to be convinced otherwise.