# JavaScript Number.toLocaleString() with 4 digits after separator

Tags: javascript, numbers, format

Is there a way to get `number.toLocaleString()` with 4 digits after the comma?

Example:

```
var number = 49.9712;
document.getElementById('id').innerText = number.toLocaleString();
```

Result:
**49,9712**

But now it always returns number with 2 digits after comma:
**49,97**

Comment: `24.3243.toLocaleString();` --> `"24,324"`, for me, in the latest Chrome.

Comment: It depends on culture settings... But I need exactly 4 digits, man.

Comment: I had to use a min and a max: toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 4, maximumFractionDigits: 4 })

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You may use [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) to provide some options. In your case, with default locale:

```
number.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 4 })
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems like the ONLY possible solution when formatting numbers under a user locale with a defined number digits after the separator. As for myself, I used a second parameter named maximumFractionDigits. It forces the number to be outputted with the specified number of fraction digits.

Comment: If you only use minimumFractionDigits, you can get more digits than 4. There is a maximumFractionDigits field too - see comment in question.

Comment: Use `maximumFractionDigits: 0` if you don't want any fractional part. For example, ```console.log(function a(ms){return `${((ms/1000)%60).toLocaleString('en-AU',{minimumIntegerDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 0})}d:${((ms/1000/60)%60).toLocaleString('en-AU',{minimumIntegerDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 0})}:${((ms/24/60/60/1000)).toLocaleString('en-AU',{maximumFractionDigits: 0})}s`}(45*24*60*60*1000 + 4255325))```.
This will produce `45d:11m:55s`

Answer (score 20):

I found that

```
var number = 49.9712;
number.toLocaleString( { minimumFractionDigits: 4 })
```

gave the result of "49.971"

In order to actually get the 4 decimal place digits, I did this:

```
number.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 4 })
```

Also filling in a country code worked:

```
number.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 4 })
```

In both cases I got 49.9712 for the answer.

Comment: The hidden gems of vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution:

call it like this:

```
console.log(localeN(value, 4));
```

```
function localeN(v, n) {
    var i, f;
  
    i = Math.floor(v);
    f = v - i;
    return i.toLocaleString() + f.toFixed(n).substr(1);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You cannot do this with `toLocaleString()` alone. But you can round to 4 decimal places before displaying:

```
var n = Math.round(number * 10000) / 10000;
document.getElementById('id').innerText = n.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. But I need 4 digits to be precize.

Comment: Edited for 4 decimal places.

Comment: This is because depending on your locale, `toLocaleString()` may only round to 3 decimal places (as it does for me), which means the extra precision will get lost.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can do it with just toLocaleString(), as Radagast's answer demonstrates below.