# Javascript display currency without rounding

Tags: javascript, currency

I am displaying currency values in javascript, I want to display $ with every value and I also want , (comma) for thousands but I don't want rounding of digits after decimal point and I also don't have a fixed limit of how many digits would be after decimal point.

It is for en-AU

for example

45000 -> $45,000

3.6987 -> $3.6987

3 -> $3

4.00 -> $4.00

Is there any built-in JavaScript method or library can help to achieve this?

Comment: This is a question and answer site. What is the question? Where is your attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: show us the code where do you want all those things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as dollars currency string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript)

Comment: US icurrency doesn't have more than 2 decimal positions, so `$3.6987` is not a valid currency amount and shouldn't be displayed as one. The smallest US currency is 1 cent (1/100 of a dollar), which would be displayed as `$0.01`. More than two decimals is going to do nothing but confuse people, because you're pretending something is a currency amount that is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Suggest to use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
   style: 'currency',
   currency: 'USD',
   minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
});

formatter.format(3242); /* $3,242.00 */
```

You can config your FractionDigits and even your currency sign :

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
   style: 'currency',
   currency: 'GBP',
   minimumFractionDigits: 4,      
});

formatter.format(3242); /* £3,242.0000 */
```

UPDATE :

if you can't fixed your fraction digits you can use `maximumFractionDigits` and give it an amount of 20 and also give `minimumFractionDigits` value of 0 :

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
   style: 'currency',
   currency: 'GBP',
   minimumFractionDigits: 0,
   maximumFractionDigits: 20,
});

formatter.format(3242.5454); /* £3,242.5454 */
```

Comment: @Ali I update the answer, use maximumFractionDigits and give it an amount of 20 and also give minimumFractionDigits value of 0

Answer (score 4):

You can use `toLocaleString` to add the commas to the number.

```
var number = 45000;
var formatted = '$' + number.toLocaleString(); // $45,000

number = 500999.12345;
formatted = '$' + number.toLocaleString(); // $500,999.12345
```

**EDIT: To prevent rounding, use `minimumFractionDigits` option:**

```
number.toLocaleString(undefined, { minimumFractionDigits: 20 });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758817/javascript-number-tolocalestring-with-4-digits-after-separator).

Comment: var number = 3.6987; number.toLocaleString() is returning $3.699 which I don't want.

Comment: You can use the `minimumFractionDigits` property to solve this.

Comment: It does not work with the `minimumFractionDigits` set. The value is rounded even though.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [accounting.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/), it has great features for formatting value in currency format.

Comment: first example in accounting.js has showing 2 extra zeros at the end which I don't want. accounting.formatMoney(12345678); // $12,345,678.00

Comment: Use the precision setting to increase the limit