# toLocaleString() is not displaying 00 after decimal point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I want to display the 00 after the decimal points but when i try to use the following:
`console.log(Number("5000.00").toLocaleString('en'));`
or
`console.log(parseFloat("5000.00").toLocaleString('en'));`

the output which i get in both cases is 5,000 and if i use the following :
`console.log(Number("5000.02").toLocaleString('en'));`
or
`console.log(parseFloat("5000.02").toLocaleString('en'));`
the output which i get in both above cases is 5,000.02

I want to get 5,000.00 as output in the first 2 cases i.e when the value is "5000.00". How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shameless reference to a smarter user than me. [JavaScript Number.toLocaleString() with 4 digits after separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758817/javascript-number-tolocalestring-with-4-digits-after-separator)

```js
console.log(Number("5000.00").toLocaleString("en", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 }))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always show or round off to 2 decimal places you can use toFixed().

```
Number("5000.00").toFixed(2).toLocaleString('en);
```

Comment: Note that this won't localize the number, since `toFixed` converts the number into a string first.

Comment: i was facing issue while using this, the number was not getting , seperated . Thanks for all your efforts