# Typescript subtraction with decimal numbers

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a table that tracks stock level changes, on most occasions the addition/subtraction is with whole numbers (-1, -2, +2, +3) etc. However, on some instances +0.5, -0.25 may be required. My current code get the correct values, but when it comes to decimals, it will on deduct or add to the nearest whole number (+1/-1). The oldValue and newValue variable are populated from a stock changes table and I'm displaying the number of change from stock.

Below is the calculation function -

```
  formatDifference(change: StockChange) {
    const difference = parseInt(change.newValue || '0', 10) - parseInt(change.oldValue || '0', 10);
    return difference > 0 ? '+' + difference : difference;
  }
```

HTML -

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
  ({{formatDifference(change)}})
  <div class="stockLabel">
   Difference
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Simplest answer is to use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead since you don't want to parse an int 

Comment: Then you need to control the number of decimals to be displayed. See [toLocaleString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29773435/227299) Or just use [the pipe suggested by Juan Vicente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70173968/227299)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't store the value, one possible way to do it in the HTML itself is with the **decimal pipe** (*number* is the keyword for decimal pipe)

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
  ( {{    (change?.newValue ?? 0 | number:'1.0-2') - 
          (change?.oldValue ?? 0 | number:'1.0-2')
          | number:'1.0-2'        
    }} )
  <div class="stockLabel">
   Difference
  </div>
</td>
```

Basic sintaxis:

{{value| number :'digits before decimal point . minimum number of digits after decimal point - maximum number of digits after decimal point' }}

{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}
For instacen, '1.0-2' means:

- A minimum of 1 digit will be show before decimal point
- It doesn't have to have digits after decimal point (default)
- If it has numbers after decimal point, the max is 2 digits

If you want to pass "the logic" to the *ts* file, you also can use the decimalPipe *programmatically*, but you have to import it in your file and then use it as "decimalPipe":

```
import {DecimalPipe} from '@angular/common';
...
constructor( private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe ) { }
...
formatDifference(change: StockChange) {
    const difference = this.decimalPipe.transform( change.newValue || '0', '1.0-2') - this.decimalPipe.transform( change.oldValue || '0', '1.0-2');
    return difference > 0 ? '+' + difference : difference;
  }
```

NOTE: The decimal pipe is in de '@angular/common', so you need to have it imported in your module.

**More info about decimal pipe** [HERE](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)