# Displaying a number as percentage

Tags: javascript

A moderator marked the question as [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163256/how-to-format-numbers-as-percentage-values-in-javascript). It is not. Notice that this reference is also answered with solutions that assume two decimal places.

I am looking for a simple way to convert an array of numbers to array of percentages but only show the decimal places in the original number. For example:

```
I want 0.0725 to be 7.25%
I want 0.1 to be 10%
I want 0.052 to be 5.2%
I want 0.08254 to be 8.254%
etc.
```

Regarding `.toFixed()`:

```
0.0725 * 100 = 7.249999999999999
(0.0725 * 100).toFixed(3) = 7.250
```

`.toFixed` is almost a good solution, but I'm converting a bunch of number, like 0.01 and 0.082. So I can't tell in advance how many decimal places the number has
`Math.floor` and `Math.round` are also not helpful.
This simple requirement is ridiculously difficult to achieve
Oh, and I don't want to load something like lodash or underscore just to get this working
Any recommendations?

I apologize if this was previously answered. I could not find a suitable solution anywhere.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of decimal places you will have at any point?

Comment: [Do any of the answers here suit your needs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522673/make-a-number-a-percentage)

Comment: @TusharShahi No I don't

Comment: @AlexanderNied No. I tried all the solutions there. The only thing that could work is .toFixed(2), but as I mentioned, I cannot tell how many decimal points the number will have, and I really don't want to start calculating it and making this into a serious script

Comment: I think it would be helpful to understand your requirements a bit better-- can you provide some expected inputs and expected outputs, and the criteria by which they are derived?  Also, I see your question has been closed as a dupe-- I'd check the link and see if any of the answers there meet your needs-- if not, I'd suggest you update the question to explain what differentiates it from the duplicate post to make a case for reopening the post.

Comment: Why not just do .toFixed(15) for example, and then just remove '0' at right. It is not elegant but I don't see any other solution

Comment: @AlexanderNied Yeah, I checked the link. It is not helpful. I responded by editing my original question, but you are right. I will update again and show exactly what I need

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios this is actually not a bad idea :) Def add it as an answer since it does what I am looking for. Not nicely, but nicer than checking how many decimal points each number has and passing it to `.toFixed(NumOfDecimals)`

Comment: @Ben You can use 'parseFloat()' to get a number without extra '0', and then use 'String()'. It would be `String(parseFloat((0.0725 * 100).toFixed(15)))`

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios that's even better. Please add your suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it as such. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45163573/215552) on the duplicate, without the `minimumFractionDigits` setting, but with a `maximumFractionDigits` of something large, like 20?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes. That's it!! Thank you.