# decimal to percentage convertion - javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript

what is the formulat to convert for example the ff decimals to percentage? Thanks.

input : 0.866
output : 87 %

input : 0.77
output : 77%

Comment: `Math.round(0.866 * 100) + ' %'` resp. `Math.round(0.77 * 100) + '%'`

Comment: The following SO post shows how to convert numbers (namely floating point numbers) to percentile figures: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522673/make-a-number-a-percentage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily conver a float to percentage using [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```js
function toPercenage(num) {
  return `${Math.round(num * 100)}%`;
}

console.log(toPercenage(0.866));
console.log(toPercenage(0.77));
```